# getting back a non array

Tags: php, arrays

I seem to be having mental issues when it comes to arrays in php. I am not sure why, How ever my array looks like this:

```
  $elementOptions = array(
       array(
          'type' => 'Text',
          'name' => 'test' ,
          'isRequired' => true,
          'attributes' => array(
          'placeholder' => 'content'  
      ),

      'subFormName' => 'content'
  );
```

I have a for each loop as such:

```
foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        //do something else
    } else {
        //do something                 
    }        
}
```

The issue is, if I do a var dump inside the if(isarray()){} I get the following back:

```
array(1) {
  ["placeholder"]=>
  string(7) "content"
}

array(4) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(4) "Text"
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["isRequired"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["placeholder"]=>
    string(7) "content"
  }
}
```

now the issue is - I do not want the following in that var dump:

```
array(1) {
  ["placeholder"]=>
  string(7) "content"
}
```

I am not sure, based on the "data structure" above, how this 'placeholder' => 'content' is considered an array.....in either case I do not want it as part of the arrays that are var dumped.... it should just be the second array in that var dump coming back.

And that's where you guys come in, why is the place holder coming back as an array when it shouldn't (TMK - to my knowledge).

Comment: It is considered an array because it is defined as one: `'attributes' => array( 'placeholder' => 'content'  ),`  It is behaving exactly as it should, given the input you gave it.

Comment: As mentioned - it is an array after all. You'll have to add a more complete example to tell you why it's doing that. Are you calling your function recursively? (Just looping through $elementOptions wouldn't test that element) .. and your array definition doesn't make sense, as you've at least left one ) out.

Comment: Put on error_reporting and you will see that your array is missing a `)`

Comment: placeholder=>content isn't an array, it's a pair in an array that you've called attributes

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example that demonstrates your issue? Where are you using var_dump()? What are you putting in var_dump()? **The most important part of your code is missing (the part where your problem occurs).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"placeholder"=>"content" isn't considered an array or coming back as an array, it's a pair in     an array that you've called "attributes"

```
array(4) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(4) "Text"
  ["name"]=>
  string(4) "test"
  ["isRequired"]=>
  bool(true)

  ["attributes"]=> // this is your array
  array(1) {       // contents of this array are...
    ["placeholder"]=>   // this is a key
    string(7) "content" // this is a variable
  }                // array ends
}
```